# Why won't this thread pause and loop?

Tags: android, multithreading, loops

I need this thread to loop slowly and pause for the duration of integerTime once the user presses buttonStart. I'm an amateur when it comes to Android and I have literally spent about 12 hours trying to get this to work. I would be very grateful if someone could help or correct my code. Cheers.

```
 final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);             // Making the button to launch the
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                     // actions below
        public void onClick(View v) {

            editTextTarget = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTarget);      // After user presses 'Start', it will
            stringTarget = editTextTarget.getText().toString();               // convert the input 'Target' into a string

            editTextPayload = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPayload);    // After user presses 'Start', it will
            stringPayload = editTextPayload.getText().toString();             // convert the input 'Payload' into a string and
            integerPayload = Integer.parseInt(stringPayload);                // then convert the string into an integer

            editTextTime =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTime);        // After user presses 'Start', it will
            stringTime = editTextTime.getText().toString();                // convert the input 'Time' into a string and
            integerTime = Integer.parseInt(stringTime);                   // then convert the string into an integer

            Thread threadBegin = new Thread()
            {
            public void run(){
                while (DOSrunning.get()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(integerTime);               
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                    }
            ;};

            threadBegin.start();
```

Comment: Is integer time in milliseconds?

Comment: your requirement is unclear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks fine to me.  You are creating an anonymous class which extends `Thread`, overriding the `run()` method.  You need to have an `@Override` before `run()` of course and I'm confused why you need the following catches unless you are cutting out some of the inner loop.

```
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
```

I also don't see how `DOSrunning()` gets set.  It looks like an `AtomicBoolean` which is good.  Are you sure it is is initialized to `true`?

```
 AtomicBoolean DOSrunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
```

If it is not that then the problem must be that the value in `intergerTime` is not milliseconds.  A value of 1000 there will sleep 1 second.

Lastly, make sure to always handle the `InterruptedException` correctly.  Something like this is a better pattern:

```
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // reset the interrupted flag
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    e.printStackTrace();
    // quit the thread if necessary
    return;
}
```